# Dart Future catchError not called in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, future, flutter-test

I am calling Future like this:

```
   //main_bloc.dart
   ...
    getData() {
     print("getting data");

     repository.getDataFromServer().then((result) {
          _handleResult(result);
      }).catchError((e) {
          _handleError(e);
      });
   }
```

In runtime, when there is exception from the repository, it will be catched in the catchError and forward properly.

However, when i do unit testing to that part of code like this:

```
//prepare
when(mockRepository.getDataFromServer()).thenThrow(PlatformException(code: "400", message: "Error", details: ""));

//act

bloc.getData();
await untilCalled(mockRepository.getDataFromServer());

//assert

verify(mockRepository.getDataFromServer());
```

The `catchError` method not called and the test is failed due to unHandled exception.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code expects to catch an error from a returned `Future`.  Your mock throws an exception *immediately* (synchronously) when it is invoked; it never returns a `Future`.

I think that you instead would need to do:

```dart
when(repository.getDataFromServer()).thenAnswer((_) => Future.error(
    PlatformException(code: "400", message: "Error", details: "")));
```

A simpler (and more robust) change would be to use `try`-`catch` in your code instead of `Future.catchError`:

```dart
Future<void> getData() async {
  print("getting data");

  try {
    _handleResult(await repository.getDataFromServer());
  } catch (e) {
    _handleError(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! @jamesdlin the Future.error is what i was looking for! I know about the try catch solution, but when I use Future, i prefer to use the Future api for handling errors.